# How would I take a 3 digit number from a Tkinter entry and translate it into an IP address?

Tags: python, json, selenium, tkinter

Let's say the prompt is, "What is the store number?" 
The user types in 123 and hits start and what's printed is an IP address in the form of "10.1.23.111" where [10] and [111] are always fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - you can't from just entering your 3 digits in your example (i.e: 123) as any octet within an IPv4 address (###.###.###.###) can be a value between 0-255.

However, if you format the User's input to take that into consideration (i.e: 1023) to create 10.1.023.111, that'll be significantly easier.

Comment: So how would one isolate these values like 10.[1].[023].111?

Comment: Start from the end - 3, then 2, then 0 = 3 digits. Whatever remains can then be the other octet.  And it only takes a simple Integer conversion for each one, ensuring that the value is between 0 and 255 to be valid.